# Does Amazon provide low cost cloud storage backdoor for serving files from a Servlet like Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, amazon-web-services

Google App Engine provides a backdoor api to their Cloud Storage so Java Servlets serving files to remote clients don't pay twice for download bandwidth; rather than paying for the trip from Cloud Storage to the servlet and then again for the trip from the servlet to the servlet client, you only pay for the second trip. Does Amazon provide similar pricing, or are we charged for both downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about *within Amazon's ecosystem*, yes. You don't pay for data transferred between EC2 (in the North Virginia region) and S3. See [the pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/):

[image]

This is mirrored on [EC2's pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/), $0 for data from S3 in the same region.

However, note that you *will* pay $0.005 per 1,000 requests for GET requests with S3.